# ASP.NET RangeValidator weirdness with MaximumValue

Tags: asp.net, validation, rangevalidator

I have a pretty simple ASP.NET page with some input fields and validators. One field accepting a double looks like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbHeight" runat="server" />
<asp:RangeValidator ID="vdHeight" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Height must be a positive number" Text="*" 
    ControlToValidate="tbHeight" MinimumValue="0" Type="Double" />
```

<strike>This works as expected, and the user must enter a number >= 0.</strike>
*Update: this does not work as expected afterall (some weird bug in the project). See comments to the answers below for details*

I then try the same for a field accepting an integer:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbGrossTonnage" runat="server" />
<asp:RangeValidator ID="vdGrossTonnage" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Gross Tonnage must be a positive whole number" Text="*" 
    ControlToValidate="tbGrossTonnage" MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer" />
```

When loading the ASP-page, this gives me the following error: *The value '' of the MaximumValue property of 'vdGrossTonnage' cannot be converted to type 'Integer'.*

I don't have any specific max value requirements in the system, so I would just like it to "default" to `Int32.MaxValue` (although I'd have to enter 2,147,483,647, since `MaximumValue` doesn't seem to accept the `Int32.MaxValue` constant).

Why is it that a `RangeValidator` of the type `Integer` won't accept a missing `MaximumValue` property, but for one of the type `Double` this is ok?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue` properties of the `RangeValidator` class return `string.Empty` as their default when not set.

Next, it also happens that the `Convert()` protected method implemented by `BaseCompareValidator`, which is used for converting the string properties to values, calls `int.Parse()` for the `ValidationDataType.Integer` case.  `int.Parse()` doesn't like the empty string and will throw an exception.

But, in the case of `ValidationDataType.Double`, `Convert()` first calls another protected method, `ConvertDouble()` (instead of `double.Parse()`), and in that method it **explicitly returns a string value of "0" when an empty string is detected**, and that string value "0" later parses, via `double.Parse()` into `0d`.

The integer case doesn't benefit from such a mapping of `string.Empty` to "0".

Hence, the dicrepancy. The devil is in the details, and [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com) is your friend.

Comment: Just a small follow-up: in the case that I leave out `MaximumValue` for the double type, this would then really mean that both min and max are 0. Why then does my page validate the field correctly (-1 is invalid, and 1 is valid (I have double-checked, and this really works))?

Comment: @Nailuj I can't corroborate your finding that the page validates correctly with "1" as input.  If I drop your controls (from your first snippet above) onto a new page in an empty web site project, inputting "1" and then causing postback (I added a button) *does* cause validation failure.

Comment: An Additional thing to note is that it seem to do a string compare for date fields not a date compare so a Range validator that will accept 01/12/2016 wont accept "01 Dec 2016"

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the MaximumValue blank on Type="Double" is equivalent to setting MaximumValue to 0.  I'm not sure you are right about the first of your examples working fine.

Comment: Yes, I *am* sure my first example works fine. I've double-checked this (see my comment to Chris W. Rea's answer).

Comment: @Nailuj I tried your example and it didn't work fine.  (See my comment above.)  Can you try again in the simplest possible reduced case, outside your application, in a new web site project, as I did?  Perhaps there's other code from your application interfering.  e.g. Do you selectively enable/disable any of your validators? etc.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea: I tried with a new ASP.NET project, and in this case I got the same result as you: the validation does *not* work fine. I cannot think of anything obvious in my other application that might cause this either... But it doesn't really matter, I'll just make sure to explicitly specify both min and max value. Thanks for taking the time to test it :)

Comment: @Nailuj If it were me, I'd want to get to the bottom of it so I could grok exactly what's going on.  Try removing parts one-by-one (then re-test) of your "inexplicably working fine" page until you've reduced it to the point where validation starts to fail... then that last thing you removed is the likely culprit.  If you don't do this, you might be leaving a bug for your colleagues to find later ;-)

Comment: @Chris W. Rea: yes, that would indeed be the responsible thing to do. And in a perfect world I would very much like to do so too. However, this project is so large with so much spaghetti that it wouldn't really be feasible. It hurt a little bit inside saying so, but with limited time and resources this is the reality one sometimes just have to cope with :-/

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to specify `MaximumValue` for the `RangeValidator` even if your requirements does not specifically call for one. In that case just use the `MaxValue` for the `Type`. The default value for `MaximumValue` is `String.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it more confusing..

In my formview (which is in an updatepanel if that makes any difference) I have..

```
<div class="Width100PercentPadded">
    <div class="Width40PercentPadded FloatLeft ClearLeft">
        Latitude:
    </div>
    <div class="Width60PercentPadded FloatLeft">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLatitude" CssClass="Width100Percent" Text='<%#     Bind("Latitude") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidatorLatitude" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLatitude" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="Latitude must be  numeric" Text="must be numeric" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatorLatitude" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLatitude" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="90" ErrorMessage="Latitude in range 0 to 90" Text="range 0 to 90" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Width100PercentPadded">
    <div class="Width40PercentPadded FloatLeft ClearLeft">
        Longitude:
    </div>
    <div class="Width60PercentPadded FloatLeft">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLongitude" CssClass="Width100Percent" Text='<%# Bind("Longitude") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidatorLongitude" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLongitude" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="Longitude must be numeric" Text="must be numeric" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatorLongitude" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLongitude" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="180" ErrorMessage="Longitude in range 0 to 180" Text="range 0 to 180" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>

    </div>
</div>
```

Note my latitude and longitude validation is essentially the same except Longitude allows a higher maxvalue.

When running, Longitude is validated exactly as expected - type must be numeric and value must be between 0 and 180.

Latitude type must be numeric, and range fails if value is negative, but the maxvalue is not checked. I can put values in the millions in the textbox and validation does not fail.