# asp.net calendar validation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, calendar

I use a textbox and get the selected date from calendar.
After that I use a range validator like this

```
Calendar1.SelectionMode = CalendarSelectionMode.Day
Calendar1.SelectedDate = Date.Today
rvDate.ControlToValidate = "txtValidate"
rvDate.Type = ValidationDataType.Date
rvDate.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
rvDate.MaximumValue = ((Date.Today).AddDays(7)).ToShortDateString()
rvDate.ErrorMessage = "Select date between today to next 7 day!"
```

During run time, I got error like this

`System.Web.HttpException: The value '26-Jul-12' of the MaximumValue property of 'rvDate' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.`
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a <globalization> tag in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

The validator will call DateTime.Parse on the MaximumValue, as you provided the Type as Date, and it is failing. What is Date.Today?

Check this link too : [ASP.NET RangeValidator weirdness with MaximumValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406124/asp-net-rangevalidator-weirdness-with-maximumvalue)